# Have somebody done/doing for regular events

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Which form should I use to imply continuity(persistence) for the event?

1- We ***had a strange woman come*** to the door selling pictures.
 (Did the strange woman use to come to the door regularly?)

2- I ***have my hair cut***. (Does that mean I have somebody to hair my cut regularly?)

3- I just ***had them doing*** stretch routines, and after, they got
 really good at it.

4- I ***have somebody cleaning*** my car.

Comment: No 1 has a different meaning of _have_: "experience" rather than "cause".

Answer (score 1):

When referring to a regular event in the present sense (it currently is a regular event), the specific verb for the event is usually used.

> I *get* my hair cut.
>
> I *drink* wine with my dinner.

However, "have" is still valid, though typically only used when other verbs don't work. This is paired with a present tense verb.

> I have someone clean my car.
>
> We have someone restock the shelves.

When "have" is paired with a continuous verb, it implies that the event is happening currently. Whether the event is regular is ambiguous.

> I have someone cleaning my car *right now*.
>
> We have someone restocking the shelves *as we speak*.

When referring to a regular event that happened in the past but is either no longer a regular event, or you're not sure if it's still a regular event, "had" is used. However, some additional context is usually required to define it as a continuous event rather than a single event.

> We had a strange woman come to the door *on Wednesdays*.
>
> I just had them doing stretch routines, and after *a week*, they got really good at it.